# closing pages after loging in

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

right ive gotten this far into creating a login page but i would like to be able to close the page after i have logged in. at the moment it opens the next page but it doesn't close the current page. if anyone could re-write the code to make it work that would be greatly appreciated. (please note that the current locations are just place holders.)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Verdana Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
admin login 
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="admin"/>
Password<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{

if
(form.admin.value == "admin" && form.password.value == "password")
{window.open('http://www.google.com')&&(window.close)}

if
(form.admin.value=="fiddler" && form.password.value=="yes")
{open('http://www.yahoo.com')}

else
{alert("incorrect password or username")}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `window.location.href='http://www.google.com';`, It will open page in same window.

Comment: I am astonished nobody has brought up 1) a malicious user could see the password in the page source and 2) a malicious user could just read the redirect URL from there as well (and type them manually in the address bar).

Comment: For password protection you need server-side code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location` instead of `window.open`

```
   function check(form) {

            if (form.admin.value == "admin" && form.password.value == "password") {
                window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
            }

            if (form.admin.value == "fiddler" && form.password.value == "yes") {
                window.location = 'http://localhost/bogvote/fiddling.asp';
            }

            else {
                alert("incorrect password or username")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "_self");
```

This will openup your new window in the same page instead of different tab..